# PHP preg_replace with multiple token replacements

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following string ($line) in a PHP function.

```
$line='<span class="cooktime">25 Mins<span class="value-title" title="PT0H25M"></span></span><span class="preptime">30 Mins<span class="value-title" title="PT0H30M"></span></span>';
```

I would like to transform each span set to the following using preg_replace or any other approach:

```
$line='<span class="cooktime">25 Mins<span class="value-title" itemprop="cookTime" content="PT0H25M"></span></span><span class="preptime">30 Mins<span class="value-title" itemprop="prepTime" title="PT0H30M"></span></span>';
```

Essentially I'm adding itemprop property to span block and renaming title attribute to content.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks for your time, JK

Answer (score 0):

Could try something like this? (not tested in PHP, but tested the RegEx using JavaScript and it seemed to work.)

```
preg_replace("^(.+)title(.+)$","$1itemprop=\"prepTime\" content$2",$line);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a try  with:

```
$str = '<span class="cooktime">25 Mins<span class="value-title" title="PT0H25M"></span></span>';
$str = preg_replace('/" title="/', '" itemprop="prepTime" content="', $str);
echo $str,"\n";
```

**output:**

```
<span class="cooktime">25 Mins<span class="value-title" itemprop="prepTime" content="PT0H25M"></span></span>
```

Comment: Hi, I just updated my question a bit more specific.  Can you please check and let me know?

Answer (score 0):

OK - I figured out the answer.  Thanks to Andrew & M42 for giving ideas.  Here it is:

```
$line = preg_replace('/\ (.*?)class="preptime"(.*?)<span class="value-title" title(.*?)/i','$1class="preptime"$2<span class="value-title" itemprop="prepTime" content$3',$line);
$line = preg_replace('/\ (.*?)class="cooktime"(.*?)<span class="value-title" title(.*?)/i','$1class="cooktime"$2<span class="value-title" itemprop="cookTime" content$3',$line);
```